# Grails Unit testing GORM global constraints

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-constraints

I have an issue where the global constraints setup in the Config are not working when running unit tests.

This is in my `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints={
'*'(nullable:true, bindable:true)
}
```

in my test I have tried this:

```
static doWithConfig(c){
c.grails.gorm.default.constraints={
'*'(nullable:true, bindable:true)
}
```

and also in the `setupSpec()`:

```
grailsApplication.config.grails.gorm.default.constraints={
'*'(nullable:true, bindable:true)
}
```

All I'm doing in my test is trying to create a domain object from a json string. Is there anything special that I should be doing to get this to work in the Unit test? This is also using the Gorm-MongoDb plugin.

Comment: Don't believe you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158341/grails-global-constraints

Comment: In this version 2.4.3 you can use the static doWithConfig(c) to set up the configuration for the tests. I verified this with Grails in another issue with Date Formatting. For some reason the globals aren't being picked up though. I thought they were for a minute, but then I realized I couldn't validate in another test. So for some reason nullable:true for all properties does not work.